# Control Source of a text boxes set to DCount function - Refresh issue

Tags: vba, ms-access, textfield, ms-access-forms

I'm setting the control source of text fields to return the value of a function (multiple fields with different filtering conditions). The form has a combo box with a list of years: when the user selects a specific year, the on change event triggers a refresh of all the fields.

My problem is the fields don't show any values unless after combo box's `On Change` events. I have to click on the form/fields before the values start showing up.

I tried to do form refresh & field's requery but doesn't work.

The text field's `Control Source` is set to:

```
=SummaryReport("Projects","G","1",[Forms]![frmSUMMARY_REPORT]![cmbYEARS])
```

What I'm trying to do is when the user selects a year from  a drop down, the fields values are updated & displayed by the `On Change` event - currently they seem to be updated but are not showing unless I click on the screen and that's when values start showing up in each field.

[image: Grid refresh issue]

Answer (score 1):

The method to update calculated fields is `Me.Recalc` (or `myForm.Recalc`):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.recalc

Try this instead of `.Refresh`.

Also I think the better event to use is `After Update` instead of `On Change` for a combo box.